# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFormula')

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do a function that gets a formula from a cell with `const formula = cell.getFormulas();`  into a script that i'm doing. But nothing appears to run... Anyone knows a solution? Thanks!

`function function_1(cell) { const formula = cell.getFormulas(); ......`

I'm trying to take a formula from a cell once my function gives me a cell throw the param. I just want to get the formula that is inside the cell that is given throw the parameter. But actually didn't works.

Comment: In your script, what is `cell` of `function_1(cell)`? And, how do you run your script `function_1(cell)`?

Comment: @Tanaike Hello! `cell` is the name cell that I want to get the formula, for example A1. And I run the function in a cell as `=function_1(A1)`

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `And I run the function in a cell as =function_1(A1)`, if you are actually using `=function_1(A1)` using your script, I think that `A1` is a value of cell "A1". But, in your script, the range of A1Notation is required to be given. I think that this is the reason for your current issue. But, even when `=function_1("A1")` is put into a cell, `cell.getFormulas()` occurs an error. Because `cell` is required to be Class Range.

Comment: So, please modify your script to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).getFormulas();`. By this, when `=function_1("A1")` is put into a cell, the formulas of the range are returned as a 2-dimensional array. But, I'm not sure about your whole script. So, I'm not sure whether your other part has an issue. So, I commented on this as a reply instead of an answer. I apologize for this.

Comment: I was just posting the answer when I saw your comment already answering the question @Tanaike san, so I decided to leave it as a community wiki for future references!

Comment: @Fernando Lara Thank you for replying. I would like to agree with your kind action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `range` objects have a `.getFormula()` method. If `cell` is not a range, a type error is thrown.

As [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75897836/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-getformula#comment133874230_75897836),  the script needs to get the range from the range's a1 notation string. The script can be changed to the following:

```
function function_1(cell) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var formula = ss.getRange(cell).getFormulas();
  return(formula);
}
```

#### Result:

[image]